# IOS Map points of interest

Tags: ios, google-maps, mapkit

I Was looking  at a few map apps on the app store etc. What i have noticed on map apps that there are pins on points of interest (example atms and bus stops ) for almost all countries(Example the app Around Me) . Im doubful that the devs sat and gathered this data then manually entered the latitude an longitude for all those points.

I would like to know the method inn which a map is loaded an then points of interest (example atm machines can be called) I.E is there a link that is available an people merely import it into their program and pass parameters too their pins

Secondly , where does google get / store it's map annotations and does it allow for easy dropping into a map app.
Thank you.

Comment: It does not necessarily mean that developers gathered all the data themselves, nor that the points are incorporated in the maps framework. It could be an external web service that provided all the data.

Comment: @Mercurial I think i found what i was looking for . Google Places